# example of styled javafx chart with CSS code

Tags: css, charts, javafx

So I've been working for a while on a JavaFx application (for internal use of my company), which works great, but whenever I'm showing it to my colleagues, i always get the response "the application is great, but why is it so ugly?" , so i wend to look for examples of styled Javafx charts, and except of the Oracle documentation, i really found nothing,  for buttons Oracle published a very nice post- [here](http://fxexperience.com/2011/12/styling-fx-buttons-with-css/), but nothing similar for JavaFx charts.

I already looked for examples on Google's image gallery, but except for Oracle documentation, there's almost nothing.

Could some one be kind and post a nice CSS code that would end this embarrassment?
I'm attaching  my current CSS code, Unfortunately i don't have enough reputation for posting images (snap of the application).
Any suggested Modification of my current CSS will be great just  as well.

```
  #appContainer {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, #464646, #5f5f5f);
     -fx-spacing:30;
}

.button {
    -fx-background-color: 
        #000000,
        linear-gradient(#7ebcea, #2f4b8f),
        linear-gradient(#426ab7, #263e75),
        linear-gradient(#395cab, #223768);
    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,2,3;
    -fx-background-radius: 6;
    -fx-padding: 12 30 12 30;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-font-size: 12px;
    -fx-spacing:30;

}

.button:hover{

    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(black, white);


}
.combo-box {
    -fx-background-color: 
        #000000,
        linear-gradient(#7ebcea, #2f4b8f),
        linear-gradient(#426ab7, #263e75),
        linear-gradient(#395cab, #223768);
    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,2,3;
    -fx-background-radius: 3,2,2,2;
    -fx-padding: 12 30 12 30;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-base-color;
    -fx-font-size: 12px;
}

.combo-box:hover{

    -fx-background-color: white;


}

#buttonMenuContainer {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, #737373, #595959);
    -fx-padding: 10px;
     -fx-spacing:30;
}

.chart-title {
 -fx-font-size: 32px;
   -fx-font-family: "Arial Black";
   -fx-text-fill: #F8F8F8 ;
   -fx-effect: innershadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.7) , 6, 0.0 , 0 , 2 );
 }

.chart-alternative-row-fill {
    -fx-fill: transparent;
    -fx-stroke: transparent;
    -fx-stroke-width: 0;
}

.chart-vertical-grid-lines {
    -fx-stroke: transparent;
}
.chart-horizontal-grid-lines {
    -fx-stroke: transparent;
}

.axis {
  -fx-text-fill: #4682b4;
}

.chart {
    -fx-padding: 10px;
     -fx-background-color: 
        #000000,
        linear-gradient(#7ebcea, #2f4b8f),
        linear-gradient(#426ab7, #263e75),
        linear-gradient(#395cab, #223768);

            -fx-text-fill:  white;
}

.chart-plot-background{
-fx-padding:0px;
-fx-font-family: Verdana;
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom right, lightsteelblue, white);
}
.chart-content{
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom right, lightsteelblue, white);
-fx-padding:30px;
-fx-border-color: linear-gradient(to bottom right, lightsteelblue, white);
-fx-border-width: 5;
-fx-border-insets: -5;
}

.CategoryAxis{
 -fx-color:black;   

}

.chart-legend{
   -fx-background-color:white;

}

.axis {
    -fx-font-size: 1.4em;    
    -fx-tick-label-fill: black;
    -fx-font-family: Tahoma;
    -fx-tick-length: 20;
    -fx-minor-tick-length: 10;
}

.chart-series-line {    
    -fx-stroke-width: 2px;
  }

.default-color0.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: black; }
.default-color1.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: white }
.default-color2.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: blue }

default-color0.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: black, white; }
.default-color1.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: white, white; }
.default-color2.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: blue, white; }

.chart-legend { -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(gray, white);
 -fx-font: Arial;
-fx-font-size: 20px;
    -fx-text-fill: #F8F8F8 ;
   -fx-effect: innershadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.7) , 6, 0.0 , 0 , 2 );

}

.pane {
    -fx-background-color: #8fbc8f;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lookup the default styling in [caspian.css](https://gist.github.com/tmazeika/c90c03c645d18722ddb0#file-caspian-css-L2820), if you want to know what's possible to style. As to how you should style it, it depends on what you find pretty, so I'd advise you to look up a chart on google that you like and reconstruct it.